# C# generics - why can't I cast List<T> to List of constrained type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have looked up and read about other similar issues to mine, and I understand that what I'm trying to do is not possible because of the generic covariance limitations in C#. However, I don't quite understand the following:

I have a class defined as

```
Problems<T> : IProblems<T> where T : IProblem
```

Which has a field

```
protected List<T> problems = new List<T>();
```

Now I want to do the following:

```
protected virtual void OnNotifyRemainingProblems()
    {
        List<IProblem> remainingProblems1 = (List<IProblem>)problems; /* this doesn't work, gives a "cannot implicitly convert" compile error */
        List<IProblem> remainingProblems2 = new List<IProblem>();
        remainingProblems2.AddRange(problems.Select(sp => (ISyncProblem)sp)); /* but why does this work? 
        why does compiler now agree that a T item in List<T> problems can be cast to IProblem but we can't cast the entire collection of T to a collection of IProblem? */
        foreach (IProblem entry in problems) /* similarly to above approach, why would this work? */
        {
            remainingProblems2.Add(entry); 
        }
        NotifyRemainingProblems?.Invoke(this, new ProblemsEventArgs(remainingProblems2));
    }
```

In my class I constrain that `T` must be of type `IProblem`. Yet casting the entire `List<T> problems` to a List of type `IProblem` is not possible even though it is known that `T` has to be of type `IProblem`.
But when iterating over the list, it is however possible to cast an item contained in this `List<T>` to the constrained type `IProblem`.

What causes the difference here?

Comment: `((List<IProblem>)problems).Add(new SomethingThatIsntTButIsIProblem())`. Is a problem. Because that list should only contain `T`s.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using `List<T> remainingProblems1` as it should work just fine - all `T`s are `IProblem`s

Comment: `What causes the difference here?` A stream (e.g. `foreach`) of strawberries can be treated as a stream of fruit. A basket (e.g. `List`) of strawberries **can't** be treated as a basket of fruit - since the watermelon won't "fit" (since watermelon clearly isn't a strawberry).

Comment: Try `IEnmuerable<IProblem> remainingProblems1 = (IEnumerable<IProblem>)problems;`

Answer (score 0):

If you had the classes:

```
class Problem1 : IProblem { }
class Problem2 : IProblem { }
```

And created an instance of `Problems<Problem1>`, then this would break type safety:

```
List<IProblem> remainingProblems1 = (List<IProblem>)problems;
```

Because it would then be possible to do this:

```
remainingProblems1.Add(new Problem2());
```

Meaning a list of type `List<Problem1>` would contain an instance of `Problem2`.

Remember that a cast only changes the compile time type of a variable, not the runtime type.

> `remainingProblems2.AddRange(problems.Select(sp => (ISyncProblem)sp));` but why does this work?

Because `remainingProblems2` is of type `List<IProblem>`, so you can add any type that implements `IProblem`.

This is different to `problems`, which is of type `List<T>`, where `T` could be a *specific type* of `IProblem` e.g. `Problem1`.

> similarly to above approach,
> why would this work?
> `foreach (IProblem entry in problems) { remainingProblems2.Add(entry); }`

Again, because `remainingProblems2` is of type `List<IProblem>`, and because `T` implements `IProblem` it can be added legally.

Answer (score -2):

Please read about "Covariance and Contravariance in Generics"

Covariance

Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.
You can assign an instance of IEnumerable to a variable of type IEnumerable.

Contravariance

Enables you to use a more generic (less derived) type than originally specified.
You can assign an instance of Action to a variable of type Action.